# Download packages in netbeans

Tags: java, ubuntu, package, netbeans-7

can anyone tell how to download cern package in netbeans in ubuntu ??
`import cern.colt.matrix.*;

import cern.colt.matrix.impl.*;

import cern.colt.matrix.linalg.*;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't download package. You can download `jar lib` with class, that lay in this package.
Most of libs you can download here http://search.maven.org/#search manually, or using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) tool.
Netbean distribution contains `maven`
**EDIT**
add jat to libs in netbean:

```
Tools -> Libraries -> New Library (Class Library) -> Add JAR/Folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you saved the downloaded jars in a directory on your drive say: /home/me/cernlibs/. Then, in Netbeans you can create a new library: Tools > Library Manager, and browse for the folder, include all the jars that you need.

In your project you can add the library that you created.

Answer (score 0):

As your question doesn't explicitly state your preferred method, this answer will detail the approach taken using Apache `maven`. (There are other ways to achieve the same thing, such as using gradle).

1. Download the `maven` binary (bin) from the [Apache download page](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). (Download the `*.zip` for windows or the `*.tar.gz` for *NIX.) Alternatively, use your system's package manager (`apt`, `yum`, etc.) to install `maven`.
2. Extract the contents of the archive to a directory of your choosing. (Where you installed Java is probably easiest. EG: `/opt/java/maven`)
3. Assuming NetBeans is installed, launch NetBeans. Open Tools > Plugins > Installed > Search. Type "maven". If you see an entry there, you're good to go. Otherwise, search for it in the "Available Plugins" list and install it.
4. Click on Tools > Options > Java > Maven > Execution.
5. Click the "Maven Home" combo box. If you don't see the version of maven you've installed, click the "Browse" option and navigate to where you extracted the maven archive. In the "Experimental" category, check "Use the following location to store Maven binaries". Browse to `~/.m2/store` (You might need to create this path.) Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
6. Create a new Maven Project. In the "Projects" selection, choose "Java Application", "JavaFX Application" or "Web Application" (whichever is appropriate). Click <kbd>Next</kbd>. Give the project a name (EG: `mavenPlayground`) and place it in an appropriate location. NetBeans will set the Artifact ID to match. You probably don't have to concern yourself with the Group ID, Version or Package fields. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.
7. Expand the project so you can see the "Dependencies" directory. Right-click on it and select the "Add Dependency ..." item. Visit the [maven search page](http://search.maven.org/#search) and type in `cern.colt.matrix` (or whatever you want to search for) and click the <kbd>Search</kbd> button.
8. From the results, choose the appropriate item and click the link. Eg: `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.colt`. Copy the relevant info to the dialog's fields, then click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button.
9. Go grab some coffee or other refreshment while maven chews up your data, downloading the required libraries.

*Note:* If your computer is connected to the Internet behind/through a proxy, you might need to configure Maven's proxy settings. These can be found in `{M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml`

The proxy configuration should look something like this:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
  <id>proxynamehere</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>yourname</username><!-- omit this if you aren't required to authenticate -->
  <password>password</password><!-- omit this if you aren't required to authenticate -->
  <host>proxy.host.com</host>
  <port>8888</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

[Source for Proxy Config](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/): MK Young, 13/12/2012

Answer (score -2):

First, you download a desired package in the internet, which should be the .jar file instead of classes file. Then, in NetBeans, in the Tool --> Library --> New Library --> Add JAR/Folder. If you do the aforementioned steps, it could not guarantee you could make sense. Then, right click your project name in NetBeans, go to Properties --> Libraries --> Add Library. Then it will make sense.